# Simple input to output program in Assembly

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64, gnu-assembler

So, I'm new to learning Assembly and am very confused on how the memory works in Assembly etc.

I got the following code:

```
.global main

.text
format_input: .asciz "%ld"

main:
    subq $8, %rsp
    leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi
    movq $format_input, %rdi
    movq $0, %rax
    call scanf

    movq %rsp, %rdi
    call printf

end:
    movq $0, %rax
    call exit
```

What I wanted to do here is to input a number and output the same number. But here, I'm already having a problem. If I input a **number**, I get a `Segmentation fault`. If I input **one character**, like the letter `a`, it runs without any errors? It only doesn't output anything.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `leaq -8(%rbp), %rsi` uses _RBP_ which isn't set. I think you could get the equivalent by doing `mov %rsp, %rsi`. _RAX_ gets clobbered by `scanf` so you'll want to set it to 0 again for the call to `printf`. _RDI_ gets clobbered by `scanf` so you'll have to set it again before calling `printf`. You don't want the address of the number to print, you want its value so you'd also have to do something like `movq (%rsp), %rsi` before calling `printf`.

Comment: Figure 3.4 of the [System V 64-bit ABI](https://web.archive.org/web/20160706074221/http://www.x86-64.org/documentation/abi.pdf) has information on volatile/nonvolatile registers, as well as  everything you need to know about the 64-bit Linux System V calling convention. You might want to also put your string in the `.data` and not the `.text` section although read only strings (ones you don't intend to write to) could go in the read-only section `.rodata` . This makes it a bit clearer what is data and what is code.

Comment: Of course I am also assuming you are using Linux, but it would help for you to state the OS/Platform.

Comment: And of course using a debugger (like _GDB_) is very useful to step through code to see where things fail, and what is in memory and registers at the time of the failure.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Wow, thanks for all the tips! Should I state in the tags that I'm using Linux, or should I just add it in the question? If you want, you can convert the comments to an answer so I can accept it :).

Comment: Adding it to the tags should be enough.